# Extract data from a string using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Following is the statement

```
Performance;#Recruiting;#Culture and values;#Community Involvement &
Volunteerism;/Talent Development;#Workplace
```

I want each value present after the ;# sign to be paste in a new cell? How do i do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to provide a code sample to show us what you have tried. Read this article if you need an idea of what to include http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've not used VBA for some time, but this should get you started at least:

```
Private Sub ProcessStr()
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strTest = "YOUR STRING"
    strArray = Split(strTest, ";")

    For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
        // REMOVE # SIGN HERE ?
        // DO SOMETHING WITH THE VALUES
        // strArray(i) - CONTAINS EACH VALUE
        // PLACE IN INDIVIDUAL CELLS
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
dim arrString() as string
dim strInput as string
dim i as integer

strInput = "Performance;#Recruiting;#Culture and values;#Community Involvement &
Volunteerism;/Talent Development;#Workplace"
arrStrings = strings.split(strInput, ";#")
for i = 1 to ubound(arrstrings)
    cells(i, 1) = arrstrings(i)
next i
```